# imageMagick: How to auto-resize a caption box?

Tags: php, imagemagick

I'm using `imageMagick convert` command in a `PHP` file to add a caption to an image.

This works fine.

However, the caption text can be long sometimes, With long caption texts, when I run my code, some of the text goes missing.

Is there any way to resize the caption box based on its content?

This is my code that I run from my php file:

```
<?php

shell_exec("convert input.png \
          -gravity Southwest   -background '#f48fb0'  -splice 0x44 \
          -pointsize 30 -fill white -annotate +10+4 'This is a long caption texts that I need to place in the image caption... blah blah blah blah... This is a long caption texts that I need to place in the image caption... blah blah blah blah... '   output.png");

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use label: or caption: to create the text as its own image in ImageMagick and append to the bottom of your image or composite it at the bottom over your image. The former will chose a font size such that the text will fit into the width of your image. Note I did not specify the height or pint-size. The latter will use your pointsize and width (no height) and wrap the text into as many lines as needed. But it makes the text part taller by the number of rows of text it uses. Pango: is another option. See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/. If I append, then I get these two results using the logo: ImageMagick internal image.

```
wd=`convert logo: -format "%w" info:`

convert logo: \
\( -size ${wd}x -background '#f48fb0' -gravity center -fill white \
label:'This is a long caption texts that I need to place in the image caption... blah blah blah blah... This is a long caption texts that I need to place in the image caption... blah blah blah blah... ' \) \
-append output2.png
```

[image]

```
convert logo: \
\( -size ${wd}x -background '#f48fb0' -gravity center -fill white -pointsize 30 \
caption:'This is a long caption texts that I need to place in the image caption... blah blah blah blah... This is a long caption texts that I need to place in the image caption... blah blah blah blah... ' \) \
-append output3.png
```

[image]

Comment: I'm confused! what is logo? why do i get Undefined variable: wd error? where does the input.png file come in ?

Comment: Tried your second code and i get nothing... no errors and no image!

Comment: The code wd=`convert logo: -format "%w" info:` cannot be run via PHP either. this whole answer is wrong! Please either amend your answer or remove it.

Comment: My code is simply unix ImageMagick command line code. The line for wd gets the image width and puts it into a variable wd. You can replace that with PHP code. The other two command lines can be called in PHP exec() once you get the image width.

Comment: To get the width, you can use PHP commands or use the following. $wd= exec("convert logo: -format '%w' info:");  The logo: image is a special image internal to ImageMagick. You can replace logo: with your own image in the form imagename.suffix, such as input.png

Answer (score 0):

Using my comments presented. I have modified my code to use PHP. This should work. You can try shell_exec if exec is not allowed.

```
<?php
$wd = exec("convert input.png -format '%w' info:");
exec("convert logo: \( -size ${wd}x -background '#f48fb0' -gravity center -fill white label:'This is a long caption texts that I need to place in the image caption... blah blah blah blah... This is a long caption texts that I need to place in the image caption... blah blah blah blah... ' \) -append output.png");
?>
```

or

```
<?php
exec("wd=`convert input.png -format '%w' info:` \
convert input.png \( -size ${wd}x -background '#f48fb0' -gravity center -fill white label:'This is a long caption texts that I need to place in the image caption... blah blah blah blah... This is a long caption texts that I need to place in the image caption... blah blah blah blah... ' \) -append output.png");
?>
```

Be sure that when you copy and paste this, that there is no space after the ending \ in the first line for the wd computation.

Or you just use PHP getimagesize() to get the wd argument. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php